# Threshold Based Classification Using a Single Continuous Variable

Tags: classification

I have multiple records containing a single continuous variable as feature and the corresponding binary label (1, 0). I've to determine a threshold which maximally separates these two classes. Now in the attached histogram you can visually determine that the value would be somewhere between 0.4 and 0.6 (classes are in blue and red) but is there a simple way to do it mathematically?

Perhaps logistic regression or SVM would be an overkill.

[image: Histogram of continuous variable Blue and Red and classes 1,0 respectively]

Comment: This is a usefull chapter about bayesian decision theory and decision boundaries: http://byclb.com/TR/Tutorials/neural_networks/ch4_1.htm. On the bottom there is an example of the decision boundary of two multivariate gaussians with a prior.

Comment: Logistic regression is much easier for you, an analytic solution is much easier for the computer. Do you really need the latter one?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Pieter. I've also been thinking that perhaps simply using SVM's would be a better idea since it would give me maximal separation between two classes, I've also looked briefly into Linear Discriminant Analysis but i'm not sure if it would return the optimal boundary. I want to do it mathematically because instead of using an optimzation technique perhaps there's a simpler mathematical solution which yields that threshold. However, compared to this chapter, SVM looks simpler.